# CR equations do not imply complex differentiability.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> Let $$f:\mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ be defined by 
>   $$
> f(x+iy)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0, \,\,\, \text{if}\,\,\, x=0\\
> 0, \,\,\, \text{if}\,\,\, y=0\\
> 1, \,\,\, \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$

I want to show that the CR equations are satisfied but $f$ is not complex differentiable at $(0,0)$. But I'm having trouble writing $f$ in the form $u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions on the real plane. If I can do this then I can find $u_x, u_y, v_x$ and $v_y$ at $(0,0)$. 
This problem is from Complex Made Simple by Ullrich. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have edited your question for better format. Please check if that is fine. You can always go back to your original format.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much better now.

Comment: Fall back on the limit definition of the derivatives.

Comment: Try $u=f$, $v=0$.